# ECDH (256 bit key), Create Private Key from X component

Tags: windows, encryption

I am trying to implement BitMessage Crypto with Windows CNG functions

I am trying to create a key pair from a single 32 byte value.

> In order to encrypt the pubkey data, a double SHA-512 hash is calculated from the address version number, stream number, and ripe hash of the Bitmessage address that the pubkey corresponds to. The first 32 bytes of this hash are used to create a public and private key pair with which to encrypt and decrypt the pubkey data, using the same algorithm as message encryption (see Encryption).

[Bitmessage Protocol regarding this](https://bitmessage.org/wiki/Protocol_specification#pubkey)

This can be done by using the 32 byte integer as the private key component.

But how can i do this using Windows CNG functions.
or maybe i can do the calculation manually?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: ok I admit a better understanding of ECDH helps. so effectively the public key is the my 32 byte integer multiplied by the "generator integer" ??

Comment: after reading more...The public key is the point H=dG. where d is the private key. and G is the "generator" point. so i use 'd' as the exponent to the point 'G'.  ?

Comment: if windows can just do the calculation to solve for the public key then life would be so easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BCryptImportKeyPiar using a blank public key(X,Y), and use the random 32 byte number as the private part of the BCRYPT_ECCKEY_BLOB.

duh..